# Css locator error when clicking a button

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am learning Selenium and trying to experiment on `cssselector`.

I wanted to click "TRY FOR FREE" button on this

**https://www.salesforce.com/**

I used several CSS selector codes but I kept getting error:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("css=a.btn.btn-lg.btn-nav.salesforce-sans-regular>span")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/freetrial-sales.jsp?d=70130000000EqoP']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("css=a:contains('TRY FOR FREE')")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("css=a:contains('Try for Free')")).click();
```

Can someone inspect the website. I felt I am not going anywhere after reading some stuff online.

Update : I tried a new css code :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("css=div#_content_www_en_us_home_jcr_content_main-par_jumbotroncomponent div div > div:nth-of-type(5) div > div:nth-of-type(2) div div div div > div:nth-of-type(2) div > div:nth-of-type(2) div a span")).click();
```

and got an error :

> InvalidSelectorError: An invalid or illegal string was specified

[**screenshot sample html from the website**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isMIz.png)

Comment: Would you take a copy of the relevant piece of HTML, and put it into this question? In a few months time, that website will have changed, and the question will not longer make sense. That will then mean that any useful answers you get today will no longer be useful, when that situation could have been avoided. For this reason, I think the question is not on-topic, but that can be resolved easily.

Comment: Please post the errors you are getting for each selector. You might look at [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors) and [this](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors).

Comment: i attached screenshot sample on the post since i am not sure how to properly edit yet in here. New in the site. I also added a new css selector code i tried with the error. Appreciate the feedbacks

Comment: Please, add the HTML code in your question, so people can see it directly here, without opening another link.

Comment: Also, this selector (your 2nd choice) should work `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/freetrial-sales.jsp?d=70130000000EqoP']")).click();`, BUT the link there is different from your screenshot. Probably your page is dynamically generated, isn't it?

Comment: There are 2 element having name Try it fre

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Xpath since there are 2 elements with same name, use this Xpath

```
 //a[@class='btn btn-lg btn-nav salesforce-sans-regular']
```